# Rails 3.2.x associations and attr_accessible

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

Trying to find the definitive answer on whether active record associations should be in the list of attr_accessible attributes.

I've seen

```
class Foo

  attr_accessible :name
  attr_accessible :bars

  belongs_to :bar
end
```

also seen

```
  attr_accessible :bars_id
```

want to know the proper way to be able to do Foo.new(name: 'name' bar: barvar)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As often the definitive answer is: "It depends™"

**Only the attributes you want to mass-assign should be made accessible.**

So if you want or need to do…

```
Foo.new(name: 'name', bar: barvar)
```

…then you simply *have to* make `bar` accessible.

In the end `assign_attributes` is called which does a simple `send("#{attribute_name}=", attribute_value)` after checking the accessibility of the attribute.

**Some coding style aspects:**

Often mass assignment happens when processing the `param` hash. At least that's where the security problems are lurking. There you rarely have a `Bar` object but more often a `bar_id`.

However if you work with model instances, most people prefer using the association methods (as @Andrew Nesbitt wrote) because that often has some advantages (automatic saving, automatic update of the association counterpart, cleaner code, …)

So there are reasons to have one or the other or both.

My personal opinion: One should not waste a lot of time on this topic since Rails 4.0 will have [a better solution](http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/3/21/strong-parameters/) for parameter sanitizing. (See [strong_parameters](https://github.com/rails/strong_parameters) if you want it in Rails 3, too)

Comment: There is one caveat you did not mention about making `:bar` accessible over `:bar_id`. If you are using STI, you must do `attr_accessible :bar_id`, otherwise you wont be able to set the association.

Answer (score 1):

You can avoid needing to make bar_id accessible by using the association builder:

```
# singular (has_one)
foo = bar.build_foo(name: 'name')

# plural (has_many)
foo = bar.foos.build(name: 'name')
```

The only time you would need to make an association accessible is if you are using accepts_nested_attributes.

Comment: if you want to do `Bar.new(name: 'blah', foo: Foo.first)` for example or Foo.active in my case then I'd have to attr_accesslbile it if I want to single line the bar.new no?

Answer (score 0):

While you can avoid making `bars_id` (shouldn't that be `bar_id`?) accessible  in your example, the question is if parts of your application still needs access to it. Using active_admin, I had to make the `whatever_id` accessible to make things work with relations.